# Android GPS Tracking Returning Odd Results

Tags: android

I've just encountered some strange numbers while tracking data using the GPS on my HTC One. In essence, I have a function that calculates the approximate difference between two GPS locations, however the results are... odd.

The first reading I get is normally something reasonable, and then the next readings are all 0.0km until about the 5th or sixth.

I calculate the distance every 10 seconds, while moving at about 50km/h so naturally, I'd expect something other than 0.0km for every reading.

Could someone spot where the problem is? Is there a limit on how many times I can get GPS readings? Thanks!

Here is a sample of my data going at 50 km/h taking readings every 10 seconds:

```
186m
0.0m
0.0m
0.0m
190m
0.0
...



public class profile extends Activity {

    GPSTracker gps;
    private double long1, lat1;

    public static double haversine(
            double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
        int r = 6371; // average radius of the earth in km
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2))
                        * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        double d = r * c;
        return d*1000.00;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        gps = new GPSTracker(profile.this);
        if(gps.canGetLocation()) {

            lat1 = gps.getLatitude();
            long1 = gps.getLongitude();
        }
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if(gps.canGetLocation()) {
                                gps = new GPSTracker(profile.this);
                                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                                double distance = haversine(lat1, long1, latitude, longitude);
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        String.valueOf(distance) + " meters", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                long1 = longitude;
                                lat1 = latitude;
                            } else {
                                gps.showSettingsAlert();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10000);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is GPSTracker class?

My guess is that first results are calculated using Wi-Fi and Cell towers (using network provider) and return same approximate location. After some time you get GPS fix and start getting more accurate location info.

Comment: That seems unlikely, as I drove around the city. Unless I got super unlucky and locked onto wifi signals everywhere.